# on which port does solr works on

Tags: solr

I am new to solr i have just installed it with tomcat, and just after installing i opened http://localhost:8080/solr/#/ and i could see the solr admin page .
So the website i am refering, 
it is given there that to start solr run `bin/solr start` ,and it can be seen at  http://localhost:8983/solr/#/
So now solr admin page is visible at both 8080 and 8983.
So i just wanted to know on which port does solr actually works on ,`8080` or `8983` ?

Comment: Which version of Solr? The standard installation is with Jetty, Tomcat is not a standard installation and is not supported starting from Solr 5.

Answer (score 0):

Well i am also new to Solr and i am running it with Jetty. and i think it actually works on 8983. although you can change it in the configuration xml file.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Solr 5 it will be hosted by jetty and listen on port 8983 by default; you can change the port from the solr command line using e.g. `bin/solr start -p 9999`

If you're using an older version of solr and you are hosting in tomcat as you say, then by default it will use the default tomcat port (8080) and you'll need to look at your maven/tomcat/whatever setup to change the port.

You can change the port from maven using `-Djetty.port=9999` or `-Dmaven.tomcat.port=9999` as appropriate.

From what you're describing it looks like you may have two copies of solr running on your machine, one with jetty and one with tomcat.